# Prepending only if the div isn't showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I want to prepend a div only if the div I'm prepending isn't already showing.

```
$(".loginForm").submit(function() {
    var username = $("input.username").val();
        var password = $("input.password").val();
        var errorvisible = $("body").has(".alert.error");
    if (!username || !password && errorvisible == false) {
        $('body').prepend("<div class=\"error alert\">One or more field(s), have been left empty</div>");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.error.alert').fadeOut('1000', function() {
                $('.error.alert').remove();
            });
        }, 6000);

        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

At the moment, I'm trying to make it so the jquery will only do the if empty if statement if the error isn't currently visible however it's not working...

```
        <div class="pageCont">

        <div class="title">
            <h1>LetsChat</h1>
            <h4>The new way of interaction.</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="login box">
        <form method="POST" action="#" class="loginForm">
            <input type="text" class="loginInput username" placeholder="Aquinas Email or Number" /><br>
            <input type="password" class="loginInput password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
            <div class="checkBox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxLink">
                <label for="checkBoxLink">Remember Me</label>
                <a href="forgotpass" class="forgotpass cfix">Forgotten your password?</a>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="login btn green" />
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" class="reset btn green" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="signup box">
            <form method="POST" action="#" class="signupForm">
                <input type="text" class="signupInput" placeholder="First Name" /><br>
                <input type="text" class="signupInput" placeholder="Last Name" /><br>
                <input type="text" class="signupInput" placeholder="Aquinas Email" /><br>
                <input type="password" class="signupInput" placeholder="Password" /><br>
                <input type="submit" class="purple btn signup" value="Sign Up Today!">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML part as well?

Comment: @ParkashKumar I've added it in.

Comment: So you want to display / prepend error div, if one of input field is empty and if error div is not showing, right???

Comment: try `if ((!username || !password) && errorvisible == false)`

Comment: It could be if ((!username || !password) && errorvisible.length == 0) as .has( returns an array of elements, if found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check whether the `.error.alert` elements exists, if so don't do anything else create a new one

```js
$(".loginForm").submit(function() {
  var username = $("input.username").val();
  var password = $("input.password").val();
  var errorvisible = $("body").has(".alert.error");
  if (!username || !password && errorvisible == false) {

    if (!$('.error.alert').length) {
      $('body').prepend("<div class=\"error alert\">One or more field(s), have been left empty</div>");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.error.alert').fadeOut('1000', function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      }, 6000);
    }

    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#" class="loginForm">
  <input type="text" class="loginInput username" placeholder="Aquinas Email or Number" />
  <br>
  <input type="password" class="loginInput password" placeholder="Password" />
  <br>
  <div class="checkBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxLink">
    <label for="checkBoxLink">Remember Me</label>
    <a href="forgotpass" class="forgotpass cfix">Forgotten your password?</a>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="login btn green" />
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" class="reset btn green" />
</form>
```

Comment: You could check for errorvisible.length in pre condition.

Answer (score 2):

The below should work if I'm understanding your question correctly?

```
  $(".loginForm").submit(function() {
    var username = $("input.username").val();
    var password = $("input.password").val();
    var errorvisible = $("body").has(".alert.error").length;

    if (!username || !password) 
    {
        if(errorvisible == 0)
            $('body').prepend("<div class=\"error alert\">One or more field(s), have been left empty</div>");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.error.alert').fadeOut('1000', function() {
                $('.error.alert').remove();
            });
        }, 6000);

        event.preventDefault();         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this type of code many times:

```
if(!$('#myFancyDiv').is(':visible')) {
    //prepend or do whatever you want here
}
```

BTW just for clarity, this code checks if 'myFancyDiv' is **not** visible.